# Search for the next user in alphabetical order by last name and id. - Table has multiple duplicate names

Tags: mysql, sql

I am quite new to SQL, and I am trying to understand, how could I get the **next user** from a table in alphabetical order when the table has duplicate last names? Currently, I have managed to go through the list in alphabetical order, but it will skip duplicate names or get stuck in a forever loop.

Any suggestions what I should do / look into to fix the logic in my SQL query?

ID > ID -  will skip an user if their ID is lower:

```
SELECT formID FROM table 
WHERE formID > ? AND 
lastName >= (SELECT lastName FROM table WHERE formID = ?) ORDER BY lastName ASC"
```

ID <> ID will cause a forever loop if same last name:

```
SELECT formID FROM table 
WHERE formID <> ? AND lastName >= (SELECT lastName FROM table WHERE formID = ?) 
ORDER BY lastName ASC"
```

| ID: (column) | Last name: (column) | Query #1 | Query #2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | Aaron | OK | OK |
| 64 | Billy | OK | OK |
| 42 | Bob | Skip | OK |
| 83 | Smith | Ok | Loop |
| 97 | Smith | Ok | Loop |

EDIT: Seems that I managed to find a solution to my issue by modifying my SQL code a bit. Though I am not quite sure if using `LIMIT 1` has any changes to my query.

```
SELECT formID FROM table 
WHERE 
  lastName > (SELECT lastName FROM table WHERE formID = ? ) 
              OR lastName = (SELECT lastName FROM table 
              WHERE formID = ?) 
AND formID <> ? ORDER BY lastName ASC LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try using the [`DENSE_RANK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) window function, which allows you to craft a ranking value for each unique "*lastName*" value. Once you get this value, you can apply a self join to match consecutive unique last names.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY lastname) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id,
                t1.lastName,
                t2.lastName
FROM      cte t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
       ON t2.rn = t1.rn + 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/enMUAAqBBcz77Ye533c7yb/1).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the ranking function, I will definitely look into that and write down my result as soon as I get the time to make the changes.